# проблема рекурсивной функции принимающей массив и возвращающий список в виде объекта

Tags: javascript, list, рекурсия

не могу разобраться в решение функции
Выглядит `arrayToList([10, 20])` , должна выводить после выполнения `{value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}.` Она должна быть универсальная для любой длины массива.

Пытаюсь сделать через рекурсию, но туго соображаю на моменте, как объект засунуть в rest предыдущего объекта.

что смог сделать

```
function arrayToList(arr) {
    let endObj;
    function toList(start, object){
        if (start === arr.length) {
            return endObj;
        };
        //console.log(start);
        //console.log(object); 
        if (start > 0 ) {
            if (start === arr.length - 1) object.rest = null;
            endObj.rest = object; 
        } else {
            endObj = object; 
        }
        
        return  toList(start += 1 ,{value: arr[start]})                                 
    }
  toList(-1)
  return endObj;
}
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}

помогите пожалуйста разобраться как поступить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обозначим через `f(i)` список из хвоста массива `arr[i:]`. Как связаны `f(i)` и `f(i + 1)`?

> ```
> f(i) = {'value': arr[i], 'rest': f(i + 1)}
> ```

Ещё нужно определить `f(arr.length)`:

> ```
> f(arr.length) = null
> ```

Нам нужен список от всего массива: `f(0)`. Из трёх соотношений можно составить две рекурсивные программы.

Рекурсия по растущему индексу внутри массива:

```
const arrayToList = arr => {
    const iter = i =>
        (i === arr.length)
        ? null
        : {'value': arr[i], 'rest': iter(i + 1)}
    ; 
    return iter(0);
};
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

Хвостовая рекурсия по убывающему индексу (если бы мы работали с компилятором, который оптимизирует хвостовую рекурсию, он бы превратил этот код в обычный цикл):

```
const arrayToList = arr => {
    const iter = (i, list) =>
        (i < 0)
        ? list
        : iter(i - 1, {'value': arr[i], 'rest': list})
    ; 
    return iter(arr.length - 1, null);
};
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

Тут краткое объяснение как писать рекурсивные программы: [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html). :)